# Analyzing application memory leak in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, performance

I have web application running in chrome browser. When I ran for long time I can see increase in memory footprint and java script memory. 
My application is switching screen from one page to another page and back to initial page every 15 seconds.
How do start analysis?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about memory leaks in JS, it may be due to an unintentional global variables, persistant closures or detached DOM nodes which are still referenced.

There are few tools in DevTools which you can use to detect the above cases.

1. You can use a [Heap Snapshot](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/heap-snapshots) and see the allocations to which you have direct references from the code.
2. You can use the [Allocation Timeline](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/allocation-profiler) to link the heap snapshot information to a timeline and let you see where the memory is allocated.